Cannot push into Mercurial, End of script output before headers: hgweb.cgi, TortoiseHg command returned code 255
Mercurial was working fine but after a few pushes it starts returning error.
I am using TortoiseHg and the log returns
command returned code 255

When I check the log from Apache, it mentions that hgweb.cgi is the problem
I can see the Mercurial repos on the web browser.
I'm running a Linode server and using Apache2 to host Mercurial.
I tried making every file in /var/hg executable by every user
sudo chmod -R a+rx /var/hg

I tried giving the script itself executable permission.
chmod +x hgweb.cgi

I tried running chown for Apache on the whole repos and it still not work
chown www-data -R /var/hg

I tried executing the .cgi file itself to see if there's any problem, but it terminates exactly the same way as Mercurial from my local Ubuntu server (which is working flawlessly).

I might have found the problem. My system has 1GB of RAM and OOM was killing it.
In my frustration, I switched to nginx and did a reverse proxy. I ran it with a systemd service and collected logs from it with journalctl -u nameofyourmercurialservice
Pushing a 400mb file results in OOM killer kicking in. I subsequently upgraded my system to 4GB and it worked.
